# C# WPF - Alternate blank row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I will like to add alternate blank row on my datagrid when data fetch from database. 
(Although `AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"` was used and it do help to visually segregate row to row, it will better if the row to row data, it will having blank row to have greater visual experience)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I is not a good idea to change visual expirience by adding some waste data. Probably you just need to modify style of your datagrid rows adding some extra space which you may fill as you wish.

For example, add new style to your resources:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Name="ExtraRow" Height="20"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                        <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text=" *** Extra space *** " FontSize="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="100,0"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then use it in your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridRowStyle}">
```

You will get something like:

[image]

**ADDED:**
And template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Name="ExtraRow1" Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="ExtraRow2" Height="10"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="4" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The code work almost complete for me. I do encounter error on IsNewItem (In <Style.Triggers>  ..... </Style.Triggers>). What I do was just delete that section of code and it work well (Not sure what is the downside of deleting the code). Besides, is it possible to have a line on top of the the row (to make the row look square, 4 direction covered)?

Comment: IsNewItem property originated in .Net 4.5. So if you work with a lower version you should better get original template of DataGridRow for your version of .Net and modify it.
In WPF it is possible to have for controls almost any visual appearance you could imagine - just template it. I've modified my answer to meet your requirements, but not sure if I exactly catched what you want.

Comment: @ Sergey, that look cool and that is what I try to build (but I yet to build it independently). Many thanks for your guidance. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you are binding a collection with your datagrid then it will not be possible because datagrid is filled by looking at the source of its items. I have a solution in mind but I don't think it will be appreciated.

In your collection enter an empty object at each alternating index. It will create an empty row in datagrid.